# How to schedule a C# Windows Service to run a method on the first day of the month?

Tags: c#, windows-services

How can i schedule a windows server to run a method/function every first day of the month?
I would have created a small console application and schedule it with windows built in task scheduler but in environment in which this needs to be deployed, that is not an option.

How would implement this with a timer or is there a better option i should look into. Having the service running idle for a full month isn't an a problem is this environment.

Comment: Look into Quartz.NET - it's a scheduling library for .NET

Comment: Just use a timer that examines the current time every n seconds?

Comment: nCronTab will also give you a schedule based on a Cron Expression you provide.

Comment: What's the problem with the windows task scheduler? It would help to narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: In C# Thread.Sleep(x); takes a System.TimeSpan value x as argument. Every time your service is launched create a new thread that sleeps until the time to the first of the next month is passed. This doesn't require any third party libraries and can be solved in a few lines...

Comment: The Timer classes are limited by int.MaxValue, 2 billion seconds is 28 days.  Not exactly a problem to have it fire once a day.

Comment: The trouble with using a sleep or a timer to wait until the next month is that Daylight Saving time changes will cause the timer to activate one hour too late or one hour too early (depending on if it's a spring or fall time change). To do this with a sleep or a timer requires periodic polling.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a [Waitable Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object. You can set a timer to raise an event at a given date/time. That is, you can set the timer for 11:55:37 PM on 03/01/2014. The timer has a 64-bit period so its range is considerably larger than the other timers (like `System.Timers.Timer` and `System.Threading.Timer` which are limited to 4 billion milliseconds or 28 days).

That object does not have a corresponding object in .NET, but I've written a wrapper for it. I had written an article about the timer, but the site where it was published is no longer online. Full code for the Waitable Timer in C# is available at http://www.mischel.com/pubs/waitabletimer.zip.

That said, using a scheduled task really is the best option. I strongly suggest that you see if you can get the policy changed so that you can use it. One common problem is that administrators say they don't want to have to set up a task with the GUI, somehow not realizing that there is a command line program, [schtasks.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that lets you do everything the GUI does, and more.

Answer (score 0):

I have just created a very similar thing, just create a new thread like this:

```
    const int MillisecondResponseRate = 10000;
    public void DoWork()
       {
       bool executionFlag = true;

      do
          {
          Thread.Sleep(MillisecondResponseRate);
          CheckTasks();
          } while (executionFlag == true);
      }
```

The variable 'MillisecondResponseRate' is the rate you wish to test for a condition, which in your case should be every 24 hours and not 10000 (10 seconds) like my code.

The CheckTasks method should just be the code that tests for the time you wish to execute your actions, if its time then simply do what you need to.

Hope it helps!